# get int value from data grid c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to get value from datagrid

I use this code

```
 if (Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text) == Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text))
                { 
...
}
```

and it is work but show me string .

when i convert it to int i got error

```
Mah m = database.Mahs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MahID == int.Parse((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text.Trim()));
```

error

**System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'**

value is not string .

[image]

What sould i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting it to separate operations:

```
TextBlock tb = datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
// null check
if(tb == null) return;

int i;
bool success = int.TryParse(tb.Text.Trim(), out i);
if(success)
  Mah m = database.Mahs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MahID == i);
```

Comment: show me error on **out , int i** and **tryparse**

Comment: @emadshn Chceck edited answer

Comment: again error on **tryparse and out i**

Comment: its work. thanks bro.